# Dividindo colunas de dataframes diferentes e mantendo seus titulos

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tenho um dataframe com total de valores vendidos e outro com total de quilos vendidos.
Eu gostaria de obter o preço dos mesmos dividindo as colunas das mesmas.

Exemplo:

```
df_valor = pd.DataFrame([[10,6,7,8],
               [1,9,12,14],
               [5,8,10,6]],
              columns = ['a','b','c','d'])

df_kg = pd.DataFrame([[100,62,75,87],
               [15,92,122,141],
               [52,83,120,61]],
              columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

O que eu queria era dividir as colunas umas pelas outras `df_valor['a'] / df_kg['a']`, isso deve ser feito com todas as colunas, porém mantendo a nomenclatura da coluna ex.: ['a'].
E salvar em outro dataframe, df_preços.

Comment: `df_preços = df_valor / df_kg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a mesma regra do amigo jfaccioni, se você quer apenas uma divisão da coluna 'a' em um novo data frame, você deve utilizar a seguinte forma.

df_preços = df_valor['a'] / df_kg['a']

Obs. Respondi aqui pois não posso fazer comentários ainda.